# SOA Practice Exam: How am I to understand P(Z=z)?

Tags: probability, variance, actuarial-science

Let $X$ denote the loss amount sustained by an insurance company’s policyholder
in an auto collision. Let $Z$ denote the portion of $X$ that the insurance
company will have to pay. An actuary determines that $X$ and $Z$ are independent
with respective density and probability functions
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{8} e^{-x/8},& x>0\\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$
P(Z = z) =
\begin{cases}
 0.45& z = 1, \\
 0.55&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Calculate the variance of the insurance company’s claim payment $ZX$.

My understanding of $P$ is that there are two events: $\{Z=1\}$ and $\{Z \neq 1\} = \{0 \leq Z <1 \}$, with probability 0.45 and 0.55 respectively. My confusion arises as I don't see how not knowing the distribution of $Z$ on  $\{Z \neq 1\}$ can have no impact on the variance of $ZX$, and a few Mathematica simulations

a = 0;
b = 1;

Variance[Table[   RandomChoice[{0.45, 0.55} -> {1, 
         RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{a, b}]]}] RandomVariate[
       ExponentialDistribution[1/8]], {100000}]]

seem no confirm this suspicion. However, the answer is supposed to be 44.6. What am I not seeing?

Comment: This is just a typo/mistake in the question itself, they likely meant that $Z$ has one of two possible values, but they forgot to tell you what the other value was.  We have $P[Z=1]=0.45$ and $P[Z=\theta] = 0.55$ but we do not know the value of $\theta$, because the problem forgot to tell us that.

Comment: If you assume $\theta=0$ then you can get the outcome of $Var(XZ)=44.64$, which seems consistent with the number you say you are supposed to get. (It also makes intuitive sense: Either the company pays the full amount, or 0.)

Comment: Confirmed 44.64 for $\theta = 0$. Copy-and-paste error by the problem author, it seems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad the comment helped.  Just to clear this question I will put that comment here also: There was a typo in the question and it should have been: 
\begin{align*}
P[Z=1]&=0.45\\
P[Z=0]&=0.55
\end{align*}
from that you can indeed show $Var(XZ)=44.64$.